# Get all cookies with name that includes a substring

Tags: python, django, list, cookies, substring

I am making this simple random post system, and a problem I've been having is to recommend posts a user has not seen before. To differentiate a use who has seen a post and who has not seen a post, I store a cookie (for anonymous viewers) like so:

```
def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
   # Logic
   response.set_cookie(f'viewed{post_id}', 'true', max_age=60*60*24*10)  # 30 Days Till Expiry
```

This stores a cookie like if I have a post with id=12, it will be stored as:

```
viewed12, true
```

To get the value I do:

```
request.COOKIES.get(f'viewed{post_id}')
```

I want to know retrieve all cookies that begin with the string `viewed` and then I want to get everything after that (so I just want to get the id of the post from the cookie). This is my code:

```
import random


def random_post(request):
    objects_to_exclude = [1, 2, 8] # Using the cookies with substring "viewed" I want to insert into this list 
    posts = Post.objects.all().exclude(pk__in=objects_to_exclude)
    post = random.choice(posts)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'object': post, 'post': post, 'id': post.id, 'pk': post.id, 'random': 'True'})
```

Basically I want to find all the cookies with substring `viewed`, get the number after it, and then insert it into the list called `objects_to_exclude`.

**Edit:**
(I don't need to check if the value is false for the viewed cookie, as only viewed posts will have cookies stored by their pk id)

Comment: Have you considered setting a single cookie (e.g. `viewed`) and store comma separated post IDs as the value?

Comment: @Selcuk, yes I have considered that way, but I am wondering if I can do it this way since I would have to change a lot of my code to do that. If that is the only way, then yes I have considered and am able to do it then.

Comment: **EDIT:** If anyone in the future is seeing this, I would recommend not to store a cookie for each viewed post because you will reach the limit soon. Read more here: https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/11912/common-concepts/cookies-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can refactor, the best way to go forward seems to be setting a single cookie (e.g. `viewed`) and store comma separated post IDs as the value. If you can't, this should work:

```
objects_to_exclude = [int(cookie_name[6:]) for cookie_name in request.COOKIES if cookie_name.startswith("viewed")]
```